# why getInitialProps return undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

In my index page like this:

```
function Index({posts}) {
    console.log(posts);
    return (
        <div>
            Homepage
            {/* {posts && posts.length > 0 && posts.map(post => <h1 key={post._id}>{ post.title}</h1>)} */}
        </div>

    )
}

Index.getInitialProps = async ctx => {
  try {
        const res = await axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
        })
      return {posts: res.data}
      
    } catch (error) {
      return  {errorLoading: true}
    }
}

export default Index;
```

`console.log(res.data)` work successfully. But I only get `console.log(posts)` undefined. why?

Comment: Where are you logging res.data? This looks fine on the surface, assuming you're reading your logging in your nextjs logs, not in the browser

Comment: I am a beginner in next.js. How to show in browser what you say?

Comment: In this code, if there is a network error - exception raised by `axios` - then `Index` will get called with `posts: undefined`, check if this is not your case. Change `Index` to `Index({posts, errorLoading})` and add a `console.log(errorLoading)`

Comment: `getInitialProps` only runs on the server side rendering, not in your browser when you load the page. Where are you reading the log? In the browser, or nextjs output in your terminal where you're running the server?

Comment: I do this his code. There I didn't write log

Comment: I do this. But I only get undefined too. Why didnt work these I only write code what say next doc.

Answer (score 0):

I use custom app. I forgot add pageProps in _app.js. After see https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app I fix these. Thanks for everyone to help me